# How to programmatically delete a row in custom collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of custom objects created using Linq. One of the property of the custom object is type. It can be either "D2" or "S1". if it happens to be "D2", then two of the rows may have type = "D2" and one among these two rows will have id having nine digits and the other will have eleven digits. Among these two rows I have to delete the row having id of nine digits. If the collection has only one row of "D2", then I don't do anything. The following code shows how I am checking if the collection has two rows of "D2". I need help in deleting the row containg nine digit id.

```
if (customerDetails.Count(i => i.Type == "D2") > 1)
{
    //additional code to remove nine digit id goes here                  
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Please tag your questions with more than one relevant tag.

Comment: Please also give us the customer details class so we know what we are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this will work for you?

```
if (customerDetails.Count(i => i.Type == "D2") > 1) 
{
    //additional code to remove nine digit id goes here                  
    var remainingRowCount = customerDetails.RemoveAll(c => c.Type == "D2" && c.ID.ToString().Length == 9);
}
```

Comment: No problem, just remember the items are gone from your collection. So if you need the original collection for reference, make a copy.